# cambiar orientación de un visor de imágenes en visual basic

Tags: vb.net, .net, ms-access

Actualmente el visor de imágenes que tengo me lista las imágenes que tengo en una carpeta (la cual me toca elegir manual mente) en un listBox y me las muestra en un PictureBox pero quiero que la dirección la tome de una DB que tengo y que no le toque al usuario elegirla
adjunto el código, Cabe destacar que la dirección la tengo en el Form1 y el visor en el Form2

```
    Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2

    ' Array extensiones para los archivos de imagenes
    Private Extension() As String = {"*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png",
                                      "*.ico", "*.gif", "*.wmf",
                                      "*.jpeg", "*.tif", "*.psd"}

    'LEEMOS LOS ARCHIVOS MEDIANTE EL USO DE FOLDERBROWSERDIALOG
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            'creamos
            Dim obj As New FolderBrowserDialog
            With obj

                ' deshabilitamos el botón: "crear nueva carpeta"  
                .ShowNewFolderButton = False

                'ShowDialog
                If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

                    'Recorremos
                    For Each Archivo As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
                                  .SelectedPath,
                                       FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly,
                                         Extension)

                        'Agregamos a la lista
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(Archivo)
                    Next
                End If
                Exit Sub
            End With
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Exit Sub
    End Sub



    'ACCEDEMOS A LOS ARCHIVOS MEDIANTE EL LISTBOX
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged


        Try
            If File.Exists(ListBox1.Text) Then
                imagen.Image = Image.FromFile(ListBox1.Text)
                'Con fileInfo accedemos a la informacion del archivo actual
                Dim datos As New FileInfo(ListBox1.Text.ToString)
                Label1.Text = "Nombre: " & (datos.Name).ToString
                Label3.Text = "Extencion: " & (datos.Extension).ToString
                Label4.Text = "Tamaño: " & (CInt(datos.Length / 1024)).ToString & " KB"
                Label5.Text = "Ultima modificacion: " & (datos.LastWriteTime).ToString
                Label6.Text = "Ancho: " & imagen.Size.Width
                Label7.Text = "Alto: " & imagen.Size.Height

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    'CONFIGURACION DE INICIO DE CONTROLES
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Panel1.AutoScroll = True
            Panel1.SetAutoScrollMargin(5, 5)
            Panel1.BackColor = Color.Black

            With imagen
                .Left = 5
                .Top = 5
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            End With

            ListBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = True

            With ComboBox1
                .Items.Add("AutoSize")
                .Items.Add("StretchImage")
                .Items.Add("Zoom")
                .Text = "AutoSize"
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        End
    End Sub

    'OPCIONES PARA LOS DIFERENTES  SIZEMODE DEL PICTUREBOX
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            If ComboBox1.Text = "AutoSize" Then
                imagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
            End If
            If ComboBox1.Text = "StretchImage" Then
                imagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End If
            If ComboBox1.Text = "Zoom" Then
                imagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: Vista Diseño]

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo prestado a esta pregunta

Comment: No me queda claro a qué se refiere la pregunta ni el motivo de incluir la etiqueta ms-access.